# Firebase compatible version with react-native 0.56

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

We are currently running our mobile application in react-native 0.56 and when we tried to integrate firebase (react-native-firebase)push notification we are getting issues that are :

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.2
>   Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app
>
> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.2

Please let us know what version of firebase we need to install to support react-native 0.56 version.

Answer (score 1):

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
```